# CRC/Parity/Hamming Protect 16-bit parallel bus

Tags: microcontroller, crc, parity

I've got a Cortex-M4 based MCU linked to a FPGA via a 16-bit parallel memory bus interface. In essence the FPGA behaves like an external memory mapped to the memory space of the MCU: the MCU presents an address followed by either a data word (write) or reading the word presented by the FPGA (read).

I want to protect both read and write against transmission errors both during addressing and data write/read. However, I don't expect many bit errors since the distance between both parts is short.

I can easily implement checking and generating of either parity, hamming codes or CRC inside the FPGA. However, doing the same (checking and generating) in the uC seems comparatively harder since I don't want to cripple the throughput. Without error detection, reading and writing of 16-bit words takes around 4-6 processor cycles and is thus rather fast. Consequently I don't want to spend hundred of cycles on protective measures.

**In the end I am looking for a moderately efficient error detection method for 16-bit data that is implemented in a uC in as few cycles as possible.**

I've posted the same on [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23538268/125123). If you know how to properly link the two questions, let me know.

Comment: Seriously... why bother?  Unless your PCB routing is unbelievably bad, the error rate on a parallel memory bus operating inside the specs of both parts is going to be very, very low.

Comment: You are probably right about the low error rate. Still, I would like to evaluate our options here. It might be we end up wiring up some more FPGA boards to the same bus in a piggy-board fashion in which case the bus length would increase slightly. (maybe 10cm max?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your bit-error rate is measurable but not so high that no level of error-correction logic would help, you should either slow down your communications rate by 1% or so, or use the "best" 16 bits of your bus and not bother with the others.

Error correction logic is only useful in cases where the probability of an errors is relatively low *and* the probability of two errors occurring is far below the probability of one, the probability of three errors occurring is far below that, etc.  For a connection between a CPU and an FPGA, either you'll be meeting timing constraints, in which the most probable causes of errors will be things like power-supply glitches (which should be best addressed by power-supply improvements), you'll significantly miss timing constraints (in which case at least some bits of the bus will routinely yield incorrect data), or you'll be right on the edge of meeting timing constraints (in which case increasing timing margins even a little may help enormously).

If you were worried about guarding a parallel-data cable that went between boards, then the primary data to be guarded against would probably be that of a disrupted communication (e.g. one that was happening while a connector was unplugged) being perceived as legitimate.  Unless very-short-turnaround transactions are required (as might be the case here), such things are best guarded against by performing a CRC or other validation code on all the words of a longer transmission.  Appending a two-word (32-bit) CRC to a 64-word transmission would less overhead than adding a parity bit to each word, but would be far more likely to detect transmission errors.